# Getting Active directory user's Direct Report not returning all direct reports

Tags: c++, server, active-directory, ldap

I am wrote a function which return all the direct reports of the active directory user but it return only the first value rather returning all the direct reports.

```
void getDirectReports(LPCWSTR pwszAccountName) {
    HRESULT hr;
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    IDirectorySearch* pdSearch = NULL;
    ADS_SEARCH_COLUMN col;
    CComBSTR  path = L"LDAP://WIN-F94H2MP3UJR.Test.local/CN=";
    path += pwszAccountName;
    path += L",CN=Users,DC=Test,DC=local";
    hr = ADsOpenObject(path, L"Administrator", L"Password",
        ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, // For secure authentication
        IID_IDirectorySearch,
        (void**)&pdSearch);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        LPWSTR directReports = convert(L"directReports");
        LPWSTR pszAttr[] = { directReports};
        ADS_SEARCH_HANDLE hSearch;
        DWORD dwCount = 0;
        DWORD nameSize = sizeof(pszAttr) / sizeof(LPWSTR);
        LPWSTR path = convert(L"(&(objectClass=user))");
        hr = pdSearch->ExecuteSearch(path, pszAttr, nameSize, &hSearch);
        while (pdSearch->GetNextRow(hSearch) != S_ADS_NOMORE_ROWS) {
                hr = pdSearch->GetColumn(hSearch,directReports, &col);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                    printf("%S\n", (BSTR)col.pADsValues->CaseIgnoreString);
                }   
        }
    }
}
```

I have 5 direct reports to the ad user and this function only prints the first value alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`IDirectorySearch::GetColumn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nf-iads-idirectorysearch-getcolumn) method will give you an [`ADS_SEARCH_COLUMN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/ns-iads-ads_search_column) structure in your `col` variable. That documentation tells us that the value in `col.pADsValues` is an array, with the array size given in the `col.dwNumValues`.

In C++, accessing an array without the index (like `col.pADsValues`) is equivalent to reading the first value in the array (`col.pADsValues[0]`).

You just need to loop through the array.

```
hr = pdSearch->GetColumn(hSearch,directReports, &col);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    for (DWORD x = 0; x < col.dwNumValues; x++) {
        printf("%S\n", (BSTR)col.pADsValues[x].CaseIgnoreString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Accessing index with [] gives a error stating -> or ->* is applied to adsvalue instead of pointer type. And yeah i read the documentation i know it return a array but accessing the indexes is where i am stuck and i cant iterate through it like normal array

Comment: Sorry, it should be `col.pADsValues[x].CaseIgnoreString`